# Trying to create a script that on form submit sends an email to the submitter if they answered false

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking on form submit to send an email to the submitter if they filled any of the questions as false, but the script is sending emails to any submitter who entered all true as well. I know the if script works with numbers as I used it in another project but when I changed the question to true false it seems to have broken the if statement. I also know the rest of the script works because it worked before I added the  "if (certification == 'FALSE') {" line.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
var FALSE = 'FALSE';

 
function sendEmails2() {

 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 20;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4];
    var message = 'Test'
    var emailSent = row[9];
    var certification = row[5]
    if (certification == 'FALSE') {
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) {
      var subject = 'Self-Certification Alert';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try amending to the following:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
var FALSE = 'FALSE';

 
function sendEmails2() {

 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 20;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var error=0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4];
    var message = 'Test'
    var emailSent = row[9];
    var certification = row[5]
    
       if (certification == 'FALSE') {
       error++; 
       }    
  }

        if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT && error >0) {
      var subject = 'Self-Certification Alert';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
       }

}
```

Comment: I tried the new code but nothing happened. neither the false or true sent an email or marked them as email sent.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing it to the following code and got it to work.

```
enter code here
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
var TRUE = 'true';


function sendEmails2() {


 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = 20;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[4];
var message = 'Test'
var emailSent = row[9];
var certification = row[5]
if (certification !== true) {
if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) {
  var subject = 'Self-Certification Alert';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
  }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Good so you did it yourself !